# Add ticks using JSXGraph core in php

Tags: php, jsxgraph

I created a polygon with equal sides(square) using booard.create("polygon",[p1,p2])
I want to add ticks in every border line of that polygon. How can it be done, I know it can be done if using lines and segments to create that shape, but I did it using polygon, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has access to the edges of a polygon via `borders` and can create ticks for each of the edges:

```
var pol = board.create("polygon",[p1,p2]);
var i, ti = [];
for (i = 0; i < pol.borders.length; ++i) {
    ti.push(board.create('ticks', [pol.borders[i]]));
}
```